# How can I remove Jenkins job parameter fromGroovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

In a parameterized Jenkins Maven jobs, all job parameters get passed automatically to the Maven using -D notation. In some cases, this can lead to problems.

So how can I remove such variables using Groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove variables like this:

```
// Remove "REMOVE_ME" variable from the build
def actions = Thread.currentThread().executable.actions
actions.grep{it instanceof ParametersAction}.each{action ->
  actions.remove(action)
  actions.add(new ParametersAction(action.parameters.grep{it.name != "REMOVE_ME"}))
}
```

Also new variables can be add as follows:

```
actions.add(new ParametersAction([
  new StringParameterValue("NEW_VAR1", "value1"),
  new StringParameterValue("NEW_VAR2", "value2"),
]))
```

Comment: can we delete specific parameter not all of them using the param name ?